# OnClick error IndexOutOfBoundsException Android

Tags: java, android, android-listview, onclick, indexoutofboundsexception

i get a error in my application when i click over an item in the listview. The strange thing is that not always happen but sometimes. Of course i need fix it forever. The log cat shows this:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 18, size is 0
at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
at it.dd.multiplayerit.MainActivity$2.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:133)
at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1113)
at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2904)
at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3638)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5081)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:781)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The onClick method:

```
lista.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // getting values from selected ListItem
       String titoli = ((TextView) 
              view.findViewById(R.id.riga_listview_titolo)).getText().toString();

        // getting date values
        String data = ((TextView) 
               view.findViewById(R.id.riga_listview_data)).getText().toString();
        immagine = ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1));

        // Starting new intent
        Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleActivity.class);
        in.putExtra(TAG_TITOLI, titoli);
        // data
        in.putExtra(TAG_DATA, data);
        //links
        in.putExtra(TAG_LINKS, links.get(position));
        Log.w("Links", links.get(position) + "");

        in.putExtra(TAG_IMMAGINE, bitmap.get(position));
        startActivity(in);

    }
});
```

and the line 133 is:

```
in.putExtra(TAG_LINKS, links.get(position));
```

The adapter:

```
public class ParsingArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    //riferimenti statici alle risorse e agli id
    private final static int LAYOUT = R.layout.riga_listview;
    private final static int TITOLO = R.id.riga_listview_titolo;
    private final static int DATA = R.id.riga_listview_data;
    private final static int CATEGORIA = R.id.riga_listview_categoria;
    private final static int IMMAGINE = R.id.imageView1;
    //links
   // private final static int LINKS = R.id.riga_listview_links;

    ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmap;


    ArrayList<String> links;
    ArrayList<String> titoli; //lista dei titoli

    ArrayList<String> data; //lista delle date
    ArrayList<String> categoria; //lista delle categorie

    Context c; //context
    LayoutInflater inflater; //layout inflater

    //ImageLoader imageLoader=new  ImageLoader(ParsingArrayAdapter.getApplicationContext());

    public ParsingArrayAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<String> titoli, ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmap, ArrayList<String> data, ArrayList<String> categoria)
    {
        super(context,TITOLO);
        this.c = context;
        this.titoli = titoli;
        //this.links = links;
        this.data = data;
        this.categoria = categoria;
        this.bitmap = bitmap;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);

        if (this.titoli.size() > this.bitmap.size()){
            Log.d("Array compare", "Titoli > Bitmap!"+ " " + titoli.size() + " " + bitmap.size()); 
            titoli.remove(titoli.size() - 1);
        }

        if (this.titoli.size() == this.bitmap.size())
            Log.d("Array compare", "Titoli = Bitmap!" + " " + titoli.size() + " " + bitmap.size());  

        if (this.titoli.size() > this.data.size())
            Log.d("Array compare", "Titoli > Data!"+ " " + titoli.size() + " " + data.size());
        if (this.titoli.size() == this.data.size())
            Log.d("Array compare", "Titoli = Bitmap!" + " " + titoli.size() + " " + data.size());

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return titoli.size();

        //return bitmap.size();//ritorno lunghezza lista ( = numero dei titoli)
    }


    //quando la lista richiede una view
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public View getView(int pos,View view,ViewGroup parent)
    {
        CacheRiga cache; //cache
        if(view==null)//se è la prima volta che viene richiesta la view
        {
            // creo la view ma non l'attacco alla lista in quanto devo ancora modificare
            // i testi delle textview
            view = inflater.inflate(LAYOUT, parent,false); 
            cache = new CacheRiga(); //inizializzo la cache
            cache.titolo = (TextView) view.findViewById(TITOLO); //collego titolo
            cache.dateArticoli = (TextView) view.findViewById(DATA); //collego la data
            cache.categoriatext = (TextView) view.findViewById(CATEGORIA); //collego la data

            //cache.linkstext = (TextView) view.findViewById(LINKS); //collego la data


            cache.immagini = (ImageView) view.findViewById(IMMAGINE);//collego descrizione


            view.setTag(cache);//collego view con cache
        }
        else
        {
            cache = (CacheRiga) view.getTag(); //altrimenti prendo la cache dalla view
        }
        if (this.titoli.size() > 0 && pos < this.titoli.size()){
            cache.titolo.setText(titoli.get(pos)); //imposto il titolo
        }

        /*if (this.links.size() > 0 && pos < this.links.size()){
            cache.linkstext.setText(links.get(pos)); //imposto il titolo
        }*/

        if (this.data.size() > 0 && pos < this.data.size()){
            cache.dateArticoli.setText(data.get(pos));       
       }
        cache.categoriatext.setText(categoria.get(pos));    
        cache.immagini.setImageBitmap(bitmap.get(pos));

        //ImageView iv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(IMMAGINE);
        //iv.setImageBitmap(getItem(pos));


        if (bitmap!=null){
            Log.d("Bitmap MP.it", "BitmapNOTnull");         
        }else{
            Log.d("Bitmap null MP.it", "Bitmapnull");    
        }

        if (data!=null){
            Log.d("Data", "Data NOT null");         
        }else{
            Log.d("Data", "Data null");    
        }


        return view;
    }

    private class CacheRiga { // classe per la cache delle righe
        public TextView titolo; // cache titolo
        public TextView dateArticoli; // cache data
        public TextView categoriatext; // cache categoria
        //public TextView linkstext;
        public ImageView immagini; // cache descrizione
    }




}
```

Comment: The size of links is 0. Are you sure you populated it?

Comment: Where do you populate links?

Comment: show your populated data code

Comment: @ZouZou is correct.  Read the stack trace.  The array length is zero.  You can access a zero length array.

Comment: posted..needs something else?

Comment: Probably your `links` isn't always populated when you click on a item of `lista`. You may want to check that or correct it.